# Mocha Before Hook not working asynchronously

Tags: express, asynchronous, mocha.js

I can't seem to get the `before` Hook to be asynchronous.

I've used a `before` hook to start it up, which it does, but I'm trying to pick up when it fails, so that I can fail/skip the whole block (since there is no server to test with).

I've used the [async] `before` hook all throughout my code, but in this case it's not waiting for my `done` to be fired.

Basically, got a bunch of MochaJS tests, and for one block I need to start up a Web Server so that I can make Requests to it to test the RESTful API.  I want to make sure that it started successfully, hence the async method.

```
describe('RESTful Tests', function(){
    // Start up the whole express server for these API tests
    before(function(done) {
        try {
            server.on('error', (e) => {
                console.error("HERE");
                done();
            });

            listener = server.listen(port, function() {
                console.log("Server Started");
                done();
            });
            console.error("AFTER LISTEN");

        } catch(err) {
            console.error("ON Caught");
            done();
        }
        console.error("At End!!");
    });
```

This runs, and shows as an `1) "before all" hook` in the test, but it does not wait for the `done` to be called.  I'm only getting the output...

```
    RESTful Tests
AFTER LISTEN
At End!!
    1) "before all" hook
```

None of the other items show up, but I'll get an exception (expected as I've blocked the port) about the `EADDRINUSE`.  I'm really struggling to find a way to catch this.

I understand that it's in a different (kinda) "thread", so I wouldn't pick up the error, but still.... *why is the asynchronous `done` method not being obeyed?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems some of the documentation out there is a bit misleading...

The Node/ExpressJS documentation state to put the `.on('error'` method on the `server` object. Seems in this case it needed to be on the `listener` object!

So my final [working] code looks like this...

```
listener = server.listen(port, function() { 
    done();
}).on('error', (function(e) {
    this.skip(e.code);
    done();
}).bind(this));
```

Yay!!!   :)